# Get list of elements with any particular property of objects in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have one java bean class called User.I find all fields in it like this

```
 Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

There are many getter methods in Field object.

I want to get ArrayList of "names" of each object in a ArrayList. This is how I am doing it.

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();

for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

  list.add(fields[i].getName());

}
```

So Can I get list of all names from Field[] array?

Or in general, Is there any other way, to get list of elements with any particular property of objects in an array without looping through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Arrays.asList()` method

```
List<Field> list = Arrays.asList(fields);
```

But remember that the `ArrayList` returned by `asList` method will be a **different class** ( not to be confused with `java.util.ArrayList`). So to get `java.util.ArrayList`, you can use

```
ArrayList<Field> utilList = new ArrayList<Field>(Arrays.asList(fields));
```

Where `utilList` is `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks.I got this output - [private java.lang.String com.trial.bean.User.userId,..,..] , how can I get only names [userId,..,.].

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
ArrayList<Element> arrayList = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array));
```